# Html link <a> not wrapping <div> element properly

Tags: php, html

I am currently writing a php website where I encountered a problem where the html link will not wrap div element properly. I have not found an answer to my problem yet, so I appreciate if someone can help me.

This is the php code I had written:

```
 ECHO '<a target="_blank"  href="' . $row["link"] . '">';
 ECHO '<div class="header-box">';
 ECHO '<div class="detail">';
 ECHO '<p class="title">' . $row["title"] . '</p>';
 $user_data = get_user_data($row["owner_id"]);
 ECHO '<p class="author">This article is shared by <a class="user" href="./member.php?action=profile&id='.$user_data["id"].'">' . $user_data["firstname"] . " " . $user_data["lastname"] . '</a> on '.date("d F Y", strtotime($row["posted"])).'.</p>';
 ECHO '</div>';
 ECHO '<div class="good">';
 ECHO '<p id="number">'.$row["good"].'</p>';
 ECHO '<p id="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>Useful</p>';
 ECHO '</div>';
 ECHO '<div class="bad">';
 ECHO '<p id="number">'.$row["bad"].'</p>';
 ECHO '<p id="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>Not Useful</p>';
 ECHO '</div>';
 ECHO '</div>';
 ECHO '</a>';
```

However, the outcome of the php code in browser are as followed:

```
<div class="header-box">
<a target="_blank" href="http://designinstruct.com/tools-basics/5-easy-steps-optimize-your-images-photoshop/"></a>
<div class="detail">
<a target="_blank" href="http://designinstruct.com/tools-basics/5-easy-steps-optimize-your-images-photoshop/">
<p class="title">5 Easy Steps to Optimize Your Images in Photoshop</p>
</a>
<p class="author"><a target="_blank" href="http://designinstruct.com/tools-basics/5-easy-steps-optimize-your-images-photoshop/">This article is shared by </a><a class="user" href="./member.php?action=profile&amp;id=2">demoname demo</a> on 01 January 1970.</p>
</div>
<div class="good"><p id="number">1</p><p id="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>Useful</p></div>
<div class="bad"><p id="number">2333</p><p id="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>Not Useful</p>
</div></div>
```

I am getting a little bit frustrated trying to fix the problem because I can't figure out what is going wrong? The other part of code written with html link wrapping the div are working fine. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: You have nested anchors elements (`a`), which isn't valid HTML.  So the browser attempts to clean that up for you.

Comment: Isn't <a> is a valid html5 hyperlink tag?

Comment: It is.  But your code tries to nest one `a` inside another, which is not valid:  `<a href=...> ... <a href=...> ... </a> ... </a>`

Comment: Yes, it is valid, but you are only allowed to nest them in a certain way.

Comment: Urghhh, that's the problem! So I nested an a inside another a which is not valid! I think I was Juz stupid enough to make such a silly mistake and thanks for pointing it out =)

Answer (score 3):

So the question was solved by Rick Hitchcock for pointing out my nesting issue.

So the answer is not nesting an  tag within another  tag.

Answer (score 1):

**After seeing the refactored code, I realized you have a link inside another link. The browser doesn't know what to do with this, so it closes them both down as small as they can.**

Try using html inside your .php file, and just using tags where you have to use php. For Example:

close the php with a ?>, then open it each time you need it by wrapping your code in

```
<?php //php code goes here ?>
```

Here's your code refactored:

```
<a target="_blank"  href="<?php echo $row["link"] ?>">
<div class="header-box">
    <div class="detail">
        <p class="title"><?php echo $row["title"] ?></p>
        <?php $user_data = get_user_data($row["owner_id"]); ?>
         <p class="author">This article is shared by <a class="user" href="./member.php?action=profile&id=<?php echo $user_data["id"] ?>"><?php echo $user_data["firstname"] ?> <?php echo $user_data["lastname"] ?></a> on <?php echo date("d F Y", strtotime($row["posted"])) ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="good">
        <p id="number"><?php echo $row["good"] ?></p>
        <p id="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>Useful</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bad">
        <p id="number"><?php echo $row["bad"] ?></p>
        <p id="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>Not Useful</p>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using pure PHP for this? Its not necessary?

Comment: As most of my code are wrapped with buffer ob_start() code, so I suppose HTML code will prevent the buffer?

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)